# Get the size of content types?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a content type hub with about 100 Content Types (including those who are installed by default in a records center site)
Checking the size of my database it's 950MB 
I want to get the size of content types, beause I don't know where the space is being used.

Comment: Wait, you mean the size of all documents that use a certain content type or the actual space the content type definition uses up? Because in the second case, I would think that won't go over the kbyte, and won't really make any difference in the 950MB db.

Comment: Or you actually mean that the content type hub has nothing else on it but the content types?

Comment: SPArchaeologist: indeed, the content type hub has nothing else but it is taking almost 1GB in space, so I think the definition of the content types is taking a lot, any idea where the space is lost?
By the way, all my lists are empty, just a couple of css styles by default, and nothing else.

Comment: Argh, this is pretty strange, I though that even on a content type hub the content db would just contain the content type schemas and not much more. Unless there is some sort of analytic/usage log building up somewhere. Will try to see if I can find anything, for now I can sadly only support you with my vote.